# Remove data and change flag on button click Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api, angular8

I have a button on whose click get API is being called. I have a condition that

```
if (res) {
this.array = res;
this.flag = true;
}
```

i.e. if I have a response it will store it into an array. In HTML I have given the condition that

```
*ngIf = this.flag
// show data here
```

now when user clicks the button first time I get a response and the ngIf block is displayed. Suppose user clicks the button again, currently it will make the API call again and display the response again below the already existing response. And it keeps on repeating. I want to set the `flag = false` and remove the response that is being viewed on the screen and then make the API call again to show get the data, set flag = true. What is the way to achieve it?

Comment: On button click, you can make flag value false and clear the array, it works

Comment: if you dont care about the previous loaded data, you would normally override it. e.g. clear the array first. you propably have a logic error in your html binding, since you already say ```this.array = res```.

Comment: No it won't, set the flag to false first, then clear the array. @user3740359

Answer (score 0):

Simply empty the array and set the flag to false, when button is clicked.
If you will get a res, it will be displayed else not.

You also don't need a flag, condition on array's length should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
When the user clicks again the button, set the **flag** to **false** and **clear** the **array**.
When the response is fetched through the API, populate again the array and set the flag to true.